# How to transfer outputs of methods to the dialog boxes?

Tags: java, methods, ant, dialog

```
try {
        project.fireBuildStarted();
        project.init();
        ProjectHelper projectHelper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", projectHelper);
        projectHelper.parse(project, buildFile);

        // If no target specified then default target will be executed.
        String targetToExecute = (target != null && target.trim().length() > 0) ? target
                .trim() : project.getDefaultTarget();
        project.executeTarget(targetToExecute);
        project.fireBuildFinished(null);
        success = true;

    } catch (BuildException buildException) {
        project.fireBuildFinished(buildException);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, buildException, "Warning",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "!!! Unable to restart the IEHS App !!!", buildException);

    }
```

Above methods are giving some output on the console, but I need them in the dialog boxes. How can I do that ?

Comment: show more code of those methods

Comment: I have edited the code @AndrewTobilko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to capture the console logs to a UI component, if that is the case, here is the sample which will create output stream and capture console output and show it in UI component. You can try this.

```
public class Console extends JDialog {
JTextArea textArea = null;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Console dialog = new Console();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updateTextPane(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            textArea.append(text);  

        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public Console() {

    //Creating a stream to move consle output to anything else
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {

        @Override
        public void write(final int b) throws IOException {
            updateTextPane(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            updateTextPane(new String(b, off, len));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
    };

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));

    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(91, 192, 91, 23);
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(30, 11, 241, 136);
    getContentPane().add(textArea);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need this snippet:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Text");
```

On the other Hand if  `project.fireBuildFinished(buildException);` gives output to the console then you have to enter a return value of this output and enter this in the "Your Text" spot or enter this MessageDialog into your method.